# Python 3 Regex Issue

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Why does the following `string1` regexp not match? I have tested it using [this](https://regex101.com/) and it appears my regex-fu is accurate, so I figure I must be missing something in the python implementation:

```
import re
pattern = r".*W([0-9]+(\.5)?)[^\.]?.*$"
string1 = '6013-SFR6W4.5'
string2 = '6013-SFR6W4.5L'
print(re.match(pattern, string1)) # the return value is None
print(re.match(pattern, string2)) # this returns a re.match object
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbkNN.jpg) is a screenshot of an interactive session showing this issue.

**EDIT**

sys.version outputs 3.4.3

Comment: I, too, get results on both strings. What is the output of `python --version`?

Comment: Ok, the screenshot I uploaded shows a typo in my pattern, I had a "+" after the [^\.] should I delete this question?

Comment: What if you use: `pattern = r"^.*W([0-9]+(\.5)?)[^\.]?.*$"` ? Do you still get `None`?

Comment: Great! Going to update the answer, you're missing the `^` at the beginning of `pattern` definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you posted, you have:

```
pattern = r".*W([0-9]+(\.5)?)[^\.]?.*$"
```

But in the code from your screenshot, you have

```
pattern = r".*W([0-9]+(\.5)?)[^\.]+.*$"
```

(Note the `?` near the end of the first pattern is replaced with a `+` in the second one)

Answer (score 1):

When I run the code you provided, I get return values on both:

```
$ python3 test.py
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x6ffffedc3e8>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x6ffffedc3e8>
```

Comment: but it is followed by a "*" meaning that the "." must be matched "zero or more times".  According to https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: @wesanyer: Sorry, you're right. But now that I've tested it, it seems like your code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the exact same code and I have a match for both cases:

python3.4:

```
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 23 2015, 02:52:03) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> pattern = r".*W([0-9]+(\.5)?)[^\.]?.*$"
>>> string1 = '6013-SFR6W4.5'
>>> print(re.match(pattern, string1))
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 13), match='6013-SFR6W4.5'>
>>> string2 = '6013-SFR6W4.5L'
>>> print(re.match(pattern, string2))
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 14), match='6013-SFR6W4.5L'>
```

python 2.7:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> pattern = r".*W([0-9]+(\.5)?)[^\.]?.*$"
>>> string1 = '6013-SFR6W4.5'
>>> print(re.match(pattern, string1))
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10abf83e8>
>>> string2 = '6013-SFR6W4.5L'
>>> print(re.match(pattern, string2))
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10abf83e8>
```

Try use `pattern = r"^.*W([0-9]+(\.5)?)[^\.]?.*$"`, with `^`at the beginning.